# How to efficiently apply a reduce-able function on each row of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a large data.table object `dt` with millions of rows as follows:

```
     event1 event2 event3 event4 event5
  1:   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  2:   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  3:   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  4:   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  5:   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
...
```

I wish to apply *efficiently* an 'or' function on each row of the five columns. More generally, I wish to create a function that that receives `dt` and a column-names vector `cols`, and returns the desired result for the specified columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An efficient solution is achieved by using the `Reduce` function (`r-base`):

```
row_any <- function(dt, cols) {
  return(dt[, Reduce(`|`, .SD), .SDcols=cols])
}
```

For example, here is the timing for ~3.2M rows:

```
system.time(res <- row_any(dt, cols))
  user  system elapsed 
  0.028   0.000   0.029
```

Most solutions for row-wise functions use the `apply` function on margin 1 (rows). This method is not advised, as it converts the `.SD` columns to a matrix, therefore the efficiency properties of `data.table` are renounced:

```
system.time(res2 <- dt[, apply(.SD, 1, any), .SDcols=cols])
  user  system elapsed 
  3.740   0.000   3.747
```

The key takeaway here is that you should use vector and list-based functions within the data.table, rather than convert them to matrix objects.

Comment: `do.call(pmax, .SD)` maybe. I don't see code for sample data so didn't test.

Comment: This works slightly slower (elapsed time = 0.042 on the same machine), but the point was showing a method that can be used for functions that were not explicitly designed to be "parallel".